# Writing an enhanced for loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert the following for loop into an enhanced for loop

```
        for(int i=0; i< vowels.length; i++){
            if(vowels[i] == Character.toLowerCase(c)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

This is what I got, but I got `i == Character.isLetter(c)` underlined because The operator `==` is undefined for the argument type(s) char, boolean. what's wrong here?

```
        for(char i: vowels){
            if(i == Character.isLetter(c)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Why did you change `toLowerCase` to `isLetter`?

Comment: ok, i noticed it should've been `i == Character.toLowerCase(c)`

Comment: btw - there is a much easier way to check for a vowel! `public static boolean isVowel (char c) { return "aeiouy".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(c)) != -1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Character.isLetter(c)` returns `boolean` not `char`. You can't compare `boolean` with `char`.

You may need to do something like below:

```
 for(char i: vowels){
          boolean isChar = Character.isLetter(c);
           if(isChar){
            if(i ==c){
                return true;
            }
         }
        }
```

EDIT: After your comment: Your code should be something like:

```
for(char i: vowels){
        if(i == Character.toLowerCase(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Note: Hand typed code, there may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must have meant

```
for (char v: vowels){
    if (Character.isLetter(v)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Right now, you're comparing a `char` to the `boolean` resulting from the `isLetter` check.

(I changed the variable name to `v` to emphasize that it's a vowel, not an index.)